# How to convert array to string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

```
$date = gc_head::select('DATE','point_no')->orderBy('DOCDATE','desc')->limit(7)->get();
```

This return something  like array format

```
[{"DATE":"2021-06-11 00:00:00","point_no":"SRT-358"},{"DATE":"2021-06-11 00:00:00","point_no":"SRT-359"},{"DATE":"2021-06-11 00:00:00","point_no":"SRT-360"},{"DATE":"2021-06-10 00:00:00","point_no":"SRT-357"},{"DATE":"2021-06-10 00:00:00","point_no":"SRT-356"},{"DATE":"2021-06-10 00:00:00","point_no":"SRT-355"},{"DATE":"2021-06-09 00:00:00","point_no":"SRT-348"}]
```

I want to isolate `DATE` and `point_no`. For example

```
$year=['2015','2016','2017','2018','2019','2020'];
```

I tried `$date['DOCDATE']` to isolate date it's not working. Is there any better way to fix this??

Comment: I don't understand how the title goes with your question? Do you actually want a string or do you want another array with modified values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = gc_head::select('DATE','point_no')->orderBy('DOCDATE','desc')->limit(7)->get();

$date_array = array();

foreach($date as $dat){
  array_push($date_array, \Carbon\Carbon::parse($dat["DATE"])->format('Y');
}

return $date_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query -

```
$years= gc_head::select('DATE','point_no')->orderBy('DOCDATE','desc')->limit(7)->get()->map(function ($q) {
    return [Carbon::parse($q->DATE)->format('Y')];
});
```

Comment: Carbon  showing error undefined type how to import this

Comment: use Carbon\Carbon; -- add this to the top of the controller.

Comment: its worked  But i want  showing my   table date instead of current date

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map function.

```
$extractYear = function($date) {
    return substr($date["DATE"], 0, 4);
};

$years = array_map($extractYear, $date);
```